# What's the order of Pokémon manga?

Tags: pokemon

I found a lot of Pokémon manga. I don't know were to start, so whats the order of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a correct order to read them as the series consist of multiple alternative timelines.

If its the Pokémon Adventures volumes, you can find the order [here.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_Adventures_volumes)

The original series, Movie Adaptation Series and Game Adaptation Series orders can be found [here.](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Manga)